# Python - Plugins to Main Program

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, plugins

I need to make a script that calls every .py file in a specific directory. These are plugins to the main program. Each plugin script must be able to access classes and methods from the calling script.

So I have something like this:

`mainfile.py`:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVar = "a variable"

        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                execfile(path+f)

    def callMe(self):
        print self.myVar

myMain = MainClass()
myMain.callMe()
```

And I want to be able to do the following in `callee.py`

```
myMain.callMe()
```

Just using `import` will not work because `mainfile.py` must be the program that is running, `callee.py` can be removed and `mainfile` will run on its own.

Comment: what about `from mainfile import MainClass` in callee.py ?

Comment: @yakiang - That code would never be executed because `callee.py` is not the main program.

Comment: @user2529202: how do you open plugins .py source files? When using standard `import` the module is executed and then @yakiang solution is ok...

Comment: If callee.py calls myMain's callMe, wont that create infinite loop?

Comment: @mguijarr if `from mainfile import MainClass` is in `callee.py` and `mainfile.py` is executed, `callee.py` will not be executed. And even if that did work, I need to be able to access the `myMain` object, not just the `MainClass` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVar = "a variable"
        self.listOfLoadedModules = []

        for f in os.listdir("."):
            fileName, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
            if extension == ".py":
                self.listOfLoadedModules.append(__import__(fileName))

    def callMe(self):
        for currentModule in self.listOfLoadedModules:
            currentModule.__dict__.get("callMe")(self)

myMain = MainClass()
myMain.callMe()
```

With this code you should be able to call `callMe` function of any python file in the current directory. And that function will have access to `MainClass`, as we are passing it as a parameter to `callMe`.

**Note:** If you call `callMe` of `MainClass` inside callee.py's `callMe`, that will create infinite recursion and you will get

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

So, I hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: Whenever I try to do something like this, basically whenever I call `__import__` at all, it executes my main script again. I even did `if extension == ".py" and fileName != "mainfile"`.                     **EDIT** Nevermind, that was because I put `import mainfile` in `callee.py`

Comment: we dont need to import it, as we are passing it as a parameter.